# get git repository from multi pipelines jobs with groovy script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have 200-300 jobs of multibranchPipelineJob , I want to to create all of them with DSL.

I have this script to get the job name

```
    for(job in      Hudson.instance.getAllItems(org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob)
     ) { 
      println job.fullName 
    }
```

it gives me the job name , but I can't figure out how to get the git repository from it.
any idea ?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "create all of them with DSL"? Are you just trying to generate a list that shows each job its git repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Multibranch pipeline project only the top level job contains information about a repository. So you should iterate over `WorkflowMultiBranchProject` instead of `WorkflowJob`.

This way you can get a repository URL and a `List` of [RefSpec](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.0.0.201206130900-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/transport/RefSpec.html)s.

```
for(job in Hudson.instance.getAllItems(org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject)) { 
      def repositoryUrl = job.SCMSources[0].remote
      def refSpecs = job.SCMSources[0].refSpecs
}
```

Note that this is applied only for GIT repositories. For SVN it would be slightly different.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , I got the following error

groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: scm for class: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.SCMBinder
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.getProperty(GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.java:66)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:296)